# Drupal 8--How do I make custom module content show up in search results?

Tags: drupal

Learning custom modules--I have made a "hello world" module and when searching using the words "hello world" (with or without quotes), it doesn't show up in the search results.

How can I make custom module content show up in the search results?

The reason I want this is because I am going to make a module that imports a bunch of word docs, that change continually (they upload to the server via owncloud), and I want them search-able. I am planning on making a custom module to handle this process. The reason I mention it is because I might not be going about this correctly.  I am assuming it is the correct use of a module and the best way to go about implementing this need.

EDIT (adding code)

Controller:

```
$ cat src/Controller/HelloWorldController.php
<?php

namespace Drupal\hello_world\Controller;

class HelloWorldController {

  public function myCallbackMethod() {
    $element = array(
      '#markup' => '<p>Hello World</p>',
    );
    return $element;
  }
}
```

info yaml file:

```
$ cat hello_world.info.yml
name:  Hello World
type:  module
description:  'A basic Drupal 8 Hello World Module.'
package:  Custom Modules
version:  1.0
core:  8.x
```

module file:

```
$ cat hello_world.module
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;

function hello_world_permission() {
  $permissions = array(
    'administer hello world' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer Hello World module'),
      'description' => t('Change the settings for Hello World module.'),
    ),
  );
 return $permissions;
}
```

routing yaml file:

```
$ cat hello_world.routing.yml
hello_world.hello_page:
  path:  '/hello/world'
  defaults:
    _controller:  '\Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloWorldController::myCallbackMethod'
    _title: 'Hello World'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
first.form:
  path:  '/first/form'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\hello_world\Form\FirstForm'
    _title: 'First Form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Answer (score -1):

Every content in Drupal must be indexed in order to show in search results page. Indexing is one of the cron tasks in Drupal so you need to run cron after adding new content in order to show in search results. You can run cron manually or you can set up that cron runs automatically on some time interval.

Additional information you can find on [Drupal cron](https://www.drupal.org/cron).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes thanks, I am aware of indexing and cron.  This module has been installed for months and doesn't show up in search results.  Other pages have been showing results.  I am questioning if I have to add a parameter to a config file or something.

Comment: Search result page shows title and additional content snippet. You mentioned just name of the module. It is hard to know where is your problem here because you did not show any additional info. Search module shows standard node content (text from any CCK field, taxonomy, user info etc). It is important how you implemented your custom module, where you stored your content in database and many other things. Maybe you should consider solving your problem with Drupal Views which I assume have everything you need here.

Comment: All the module does is print "Hello World".  I have added the code above under EDIT.

Comment: I was away for some time... Did you found solution? I don't have experience in Drupal 8 module development but I'm pretty sure you need to implement hook in your module in order to have communication with search module or Drupal core itself. I don't see here hook for search module. If you found solution already post it.

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution yet... a hook?

Comment: I just googled "drupal 8 search hooks to index content" which brought up a number of things to explore...  I will look into it and get back.